# Output of Xlswriter in django DateField isn't correct

Tags: python, django

I used the xlsxwriter package to get the excel output form my django project(Exactly form my models). 
**These are my fields:**

```
date1 = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
date2 = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
```

The output of all fields is completely and correctly embedded in Excel, the only problem is that the fields of `DateField`  do not output correctly. The output of these fields:

```
43603
```

What should I do to fix the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I finally found the answer!**
I read more about  `xlsxwriter` and I also reviewed [this](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_dates_and_time.html) document. Written here:

> Dates and times in Excel are represented by real numbers, for example
>   “Jan 1 2013 12:00 PM” is represented by the number 41275.5.
>
> The integer part of the number stores the number of days since the
>   epoch and the fractional part stores the percentage of the day.

**and finally the answer:**

> To display the number as a date you must apply an Excel number format
>   to it.

**Here are some examples:**

```
import xlsxwriter    
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('date_examples.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Widen column A for extra visibility.
worksheet.set_column('A:A', 30)

# A number to convert to a date.
number = 41333.5

# Write it as a number without formatting.
worksheet.write('A1', number)                # 41333.5

format2 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'dd/mm/yy'})
worksheet.write('A2', number, format2)       # 28/02/13

format3 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'mm/dd/yy'})
worksheet.write('A3', number, format3)       # 02/28/13


workbook.close()
```